# Eloquent - Adding custom field like timestamps in all model by default with logged user data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-jetstream

I would like to add to all models on my Laravel project two custom fields called `updated_by` and `created_by`, automatically filled and saved on db with the name of the logged user (I'm using JetStream), exactly like the fields `updated_at` and `created_at`.

I wonder if there is a clean procedure, before starting to add the fields on model one-by-one, and handle them in the controllers, in every `store`/`update` function I have. Extending Model and using the new class for every models seems a good solution, but I'm not really sure. And I do not know how and where to fill one-time the fields with logger user data.

Thanks, I'm newbie in Laravel and hope this is not a basic question.

Comment: Extending the Model can definitely work, you'd simply add a method to set those values on `create()`, `save()`, `update()`, etc. You'd have to handle the possibility that you don't want to save those (see `public $timestamps = false;` for `created_at` and `updated_at`). Alternatively, you can use a Trait, similar to `use SoftDeletes;`, which can be set for individual Models (more granular control). Either approach is fine, both have pros and cons. This question might not be the best fit for Stackoverflow though, as opinionated questions/answers are discouraged.

Comment: Ok, thanks I got the point! I thought there was only one clean method for adding a 'custom standard column', and therefore that this was not a opinionated question.